# Passing result of expression by reference

Tags: c++, reference, rvalue

I have a function:

```
  int f(std::atomic<bool>& flag);
```

That needs to check the value of `flag`, an atomic bool which gets changed by another thread. This function works as expected (`f` sees changes to the flag made by the other thread) if I call it like so:

```
f(m_flag1);
```

What I am trying to achieve now, is slightly more complicated, since I don't want to pass a reference to a single atomic bool, but to an expression instead, like:

```
std::atomic<bool> x = m_flag1 && m_flag2;
f(x);
```

As far as I understood, it would be wrong to directly pass the expression to the function, since that would be a temporary value that would gets destroyed once the function is called. It seems to me that r-values cannot be passed as reference too.
Having a reference to `x` does not help much, though, since I think the expression is only evaluated once, so `f` is not actually seeing `m_flag1 && m_flag2`.

What is a clean way to get a reference to an expression? Should my other thread continuously evaluate `x = m_flag1 && m_flag2;` or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: It is strange you have to pass expression, (or interface is wrong).

Comment: Note that you cannot work with two atomic variables at once in an atomic way. Even `m_flag1 && m_flag2` reads (atomically) the values of both flags at different time.

Comment: `What is a clean way to get a reference to an expression?` A function.

Comment: If the function needs to work with atomic variables `m_flag1` and `m_flag2`, you need to pass them by reference to the function both separately (for instance, by two separate parameters). It cannot be done with a single reference-to-single-atomic parameter only.

Comment: Thank you all. The thing is, that function is usually called with one flag only, this is a special case in which I need two flags (or the result of the expression). Conceptually, that function needs to check a boolean expression, no matter if that is an atomic bool or a more complex expression.

Comment: @KamilCuk are you suggesting I should implement a function returning the expression result and passing that result as a reference to my `f` function?

Comment: `and passing that result` No, you have to _refactor_ your function `f` to take a function pointer, or at best an object that provides basic `operator ! && bool etc.` boolean conversion and some operators and then in those operator overloads inside that object implement your logic. But I think `foo(std::function<bool()> flag)` and then `foo([flag1, flag2](){ return flag1 && flag2; })` would be just enough.

Comment: @godo Are you saying that you have a function that in some cases needs to work with an atomic variable shared between threads and in other cases it needs to work only with a fixed boolean value?

Comment: Note that `a && b` is not atomic even if `a` and `b` both are. I don't think you can avoid explicit synchronization here.

Comment: If you actually need an atomic-pair-of-flags, you could just switch to `atomic<int>`, put the two flags in separate bits, and change the existing stores to `|=` or similar. But you really need to clarify your usage inside the function - does it check the condition repeatedly, or just once, or what?

Comment: Reference to what? References refer to variables. If you don't have a variable, you can't have a reference to it. And why would you want that in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

From question comments:

> *"[...]that fuction needs to **check** a boolean expression[...]"*

*<sup>emphasis mine</sup>*

If your function is not supposed to modify the boolean flags but only evaluate its value, then you can just take the parameter as a `const` reference instead.

```
int f(const std::atomic<bool> & flag)
{
    // ...
}
```

And the call may be like:

```
int result = f(flag1 && flag2);
```

***Note:** If you need to evaluate both flags "at the same time" (which is most probably the case), you'll need to add a synchronization mechanism such as mutexes because the expression evaluation `flag1 && flag2` is not atomic, no matter if `flag1` and `flag2` are.*

---

Now, if your function may **modify** the flags, and thus taking as a `const` reference being impossible, you don't have any other choice than to give the flags as two separate arguments and **defer the evaluation inside the function**.

From question comments again:

> *"The thing is, that function is usually called with one flag only, this is a special case in which I need two flags"*

Considering this, you can overload the function to handle the cases with one or two parameters, something as follows:

```
int f(std::atomic<bool> & flag)
{
    // ...
}
int f(std::atomic<bool> & flag1, std::atomic<bool> & flag2)
{
    auto expr_result = flag1 && flag2; // Evaluation of the expression deferred into the function
    // ...
}
```

*<sub>The note above about the need of a synchronization mechanism (such as mutexes) if you want to make the evaluation of the expression atomic still applies here.</sub>*